# Upgrading postgres 9.5 to 11

Tags: postgresql

So ive been tasked of upgrading our postgres server to version 11, however all the guide ive found either dont work for me or are not complete. 
 I have tried 2 methods and had to recall all changes:

https://www.hutsky.cz/blog/2019/02/upgrade-postgresql-from-9-3-to-11/
In this method not only are the dependency checks and upgrade commands exactly the same but also none of these commands work for me, i keep getting the error of:

"You must identify the directory where the new cluster binaries reside.
Please use the -B command-line option or the PGBINNEW environment variable.
Failure, exiting"
And ive been unable to find any fix to this.
And also tried the delete old method :

https://techcyclist.com/postgres/upgrading-postgres-to-the-latest-version-on-centos-7-server/
but in this method he deletes the old postgres completely and also the config files, but our config files have been made by the EX sys admin and i simply dont have the time it takes to study the configs to redo them in the new version, and i cant risk simply replacing the new config file with the ole one.

If anyone has done such a assignment and is willing to help, i would much appreciate it.

I used : yum install postgresql11 postgresql11-contrib postgresql11-devel postgresql11-libs postgresql11-server

to install the new postgres 11 and :

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data
```

to init it. with a few dependencies installing in between.

afterwards all other commands :

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/ --
new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/ --old-
datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/ --new-
datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/ --check
```

gave errors as described.

Comment: May i know your installation type? It is RPM or standard bitrock installers? Also what command you used? What is the output of dependency checks command?

Comment: Did you specify the old and new binary directories along with the old and new data directories?  The error message suggests at least the new binary directory parameter has been omitted.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** statements you used to run `pg_upgrade`. Also which operating system or Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replys! Well i used the exact commands in the guide, yum installed the postgres-11. I could not find in there how to define the data directory. The data directory when i tried to do it gave me the error that the path does not exist.

Comment: Did you enter the command exactly as shown? Or did you do that on a single line?

Comment: no i did them exactly as shown, only the init had a typo in the end " so i didnt put that in. Oh and also i changed the 9.3 to 9.5 since our current version is 9.5.

Comment: Well, then the parameters on the subsequent lines weren't recognized. If you enter a multiline command you must end each line with \ and the parameter name must also stay complete, you can't split `--old-datadir` in the middle as you did (or start a parameter with `--` and the continue the rest on the next line.

Comment: hmm well thanks for your time ill have to digest this for a bit, im in fact quite freshly finished the school and this bit is way confusing atm :D

Comment: well i found another command from another site: /usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_upgrade –old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/ –new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/ –old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data –new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data –check pgsql-9.5/ pgsql-11/ . But sadly i end with the same exact error that i have to identify old cluster

Comment: this command is all in the same line

Comment: Oh i figured out finally what you ment and put the enitre thing on the single row and it worked! Thank you.